# SQL Server Database Project dbml file is always modified

Tags: sql-server, git, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I created a solution which includes a bunch of DLLs, a website and a SQL Server Database project.

In this project, Visual Studio seems to maintain a .dbml file. The problem is that every time I open the solution, this file gets modified and my source control system (Git) wants to check it in.

Question is, can I safely ignore the changes made to this file? Should I exclude it from the repository?

Comment: You can safely ignore the changes or exclude the file from source consideration (preferred as TFS does this by default). Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489763/why-does-my-db-projects-dbmdl-file-change-even-when-i-make-no-changes-to-the-p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495720/c-sharp-where-does-the-dbml-file-come-from - Short explanation of what the dbml file is.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 thanks! I guess this is the answer! Can you please create an Answer (and not a Comment) so that I can mark it as the right answer?

Comment: No worries, I flagged the question as a dupe since someone else already did the work I was gonna do.